# Serverless too many files open error using chrome-aws-lambda

Tags: node.js, chromium, chrome-aws-lambda

I am trying to run chromium on aws lambda. After adding it to my dependencies in serverless file when I run yarn run serverless deploy I am getting error.

**Everything works if I uninstall chrome-aws-lambda. Problem only occurs when I install this package**

node-version: 18.x.x
dependencies:
"serverless": "^3.38.0",
"chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0"

```
Cannot read file node_modules\chrome-aws-lambda\build\puppeteer\lib\ElementHandle.d.ts due to: EMFILE: too many open files, open
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this are welcome.

I am trying to run chromium on aws lambda. After adding it to my dependencies in serverless file when I run yarn run serverless deploy I am getting error.

Tutorial I am looking into for reference:
https://oxylabs.io/blog/puppeteer-on-aws-lambda